# Using Tasks : ContinueWith needs a return statement which my business logic doesn't require

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I started using Tasks yesterday for a little project of mine. After setting up the task logic in the code, I realised that I was forced to use a return statement within my ContinueWith() function.

Is there any way to avoid having a return inside the ContinueWith even though `myTask` needs to return an object in the first place?

```
Task<List<Object>> myTask = Task<List<Object>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //business logic creating an Object to return 
    //return Object created
})
.ContinueWith<List<Object>>((antecedant) =>
{
    //business logic : needs to use antecedant
    return null; //can i get rid of this? I don't need to return an object in this section
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Let's just say the return null statement is annoying me...

Note : in response to Yuval's comment, I'm using .net framework 4.5

#### Solution

According to CoryNelson's comment, I've come up with this code. It corresponds perfectly to my needs.

```
Task<List<Object>> myTask = Task<List<Object>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //business logic creating an Object to return 
    //return Object created
});
Task myFollowingTask = myTask.ContinueWith((antecedant) =>
{
    //business logic using antecedant
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I don't need a return statement in the ContinueWith anymore.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) is where I went to get the info that I needed. See the code example

Comment: There is an overload that takes an Action instead of a function. You should be able to just get rid of your return and have it work.

Comment: @Cory Nelson Thanks, I'll look it up! You are refering to a ContinueWith overload, correct?

Comment: Why do you want a `Task<List<object>>` then? Why not a `Task` instead of you don't need the return type.

Comment: Because I need to use antecedant in the ContinueWith. antecedant will be the <List<Object>> created and returned from `myTask`.

Comment: You can split them up to two individual tasks. BTW, which version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov : Ya I'm testing it as I'm writing this comment. That is what Cory Nelson was implying in his comment. Oh, I'm using Framework version 4.5

Comment: @CoryNelson Works like a charm. I'll add it to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways that you can attack the problem:

Split up declaration of the task variables:

```
Task<List<Object>> myTask = Task<List<Object>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //business logic creating an Object to return 
    //return Object created
});

Task taskContinuation = myTask.ContinueWith((antecedant) =>
{
    //business logic : needs to use antecedant
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This will allow you to run these two tasks independently, where `continuation` is of type `Task`.

The second, and the better approach IMO would be to use `async-await`:

```
public async Task CreateFooAsync()
{
    List<object> objects = await Task.Run(() => /* Create object */);
    // here you're on the UI thread, continue execution flow as normal.
}
```

Note that semantics of `async-await` means that the first task will asynchronously wait for the objects to be created.

Comment: You can just make the overall definition be of type `Task` without splitting them. The fact that `StartNew` returns a `Task<List<Object>>` doesn't stop `myTask` from being a `Task` as it is defined by the type of `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @Guvante I think he wants the returned `List<object>` to be reachable outside the `Task`. That wont work if the type is a plain `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the result outside of the task, you will need to feed that result to the output of `myTask`.

```
Task<List<Object>> myTask = Task<List<Object>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //business logic creating an Object to return 
    //return Object created
})
.ContinueWith((antecedant) =>
{
    //business logic : needs to use antecedant
    return antecedant.Result;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This will results in `myTask.Result` being the same as `antecedant.Result` within `ContinueWith`.

Comment: This wont compile. `myTask` expects a return type from `ContinueWith`, which you aren't supplying.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Just missed adjusting the type of `myTask` which is a non-generic `Task` in this case (as the overall Task does not need a return type)